# DOM received from website doesn't have <a> link

Tags: python, xpath, mechanize

I am using  `mechanize.Browser().Open("http://urltoscrape.com")`

But the weird thing is that if I see the DOM from `mechanize.Browser().response().read()`, it doesn't contain `<a>` link element. However if I browse the website using firefox I can see the `<a>` link element in source.

I get this from `mechanize.Browser().response().read()`:

```
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
dodo4("PGEgaHJlZj0iZ3JhcGhpcy1nYWxzLV8xNTAtLS1lbGVtZW50LWNyeXN0YWwtMTYtMi04Lmh0bWwiIHRpdGxlPSJZdW1hIEFzYW1pIC8gZ3JhcGhpcyBnYWxzICMxNTAgLSBlbGVtZW50IGNyeXN0YWwgbmV4dCAxNiBwaWN0dXJlcyIgIG9uTW91c2VPdmVyPSJzd2FwKCduZXh0JywxKSIgb25Nb3VzZU91dD0ic3dhcCgnbmV4dCcsMCkiIG9uQ2xpY2s9InNob3dpdD1mYWxzZSI+PGltZyBuYW1lPSJuZXh0IiBzcmM9Imh0dHA6Ly9pbWcuYm9ieC5jb20vaW1hZ2VzL25leHQwLmdpZiIgYm9yZGVyPSIwIiBBTFQ9Im5leHQiIFdJRFRIPSIzMiIgSEVJR0hUPSIyNCIgQUxJR049IlJJR0hUIj48L0E+");
</script>
```

but in firefox I see the link  too below this javascript code:

```
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
dodo4("PGEgaHJlZj0iZ3JhcGhpcy1nYWxzLV8xNTAtLS1lbGVtZW50LWNyeXN0YWwtMTYtMi04Lmh0bWwiIHRpdGxlPSJZdW1hIEFzYW1pIC8gZ3JhcGhpcyBnYWxzICMxNTAgLSBlbGVtZW50IGNyeXN0YWwgbmV4dCAxNiBwaWN0dXJlcyIgIG9uTW91c2VPdmVyPSJzd2FwKCduZXh0JywxKSIgb25Nb3VzZU91dD0ic3dhcCgnbmV4dCcsMCkiIG9uQ2xpY2s9InNob3dpdD1mYWxzZSI+PGltZyBuYW1lPSJuZXh0IiBzcmM9Imh0dHA6Ly9pbWcuYm9ieC5jb20vaW1hZ2VzL25leHQwLmdpZiIgYm9yZGVyPSIwIiBBTFQ9Im5leHQiIFdJRFRIPSIzMiIgSEVJR0hUPSIyNCIgQUxJR049IlJJR0hUIj48L0E+");
</script>
<a onclick="showit=false" onmouseout="swap('next',0)" onmouseover="swap('next',1)" title="hello world" href="next-page.html">
</a>
```

Comment: Have you tried faking the user agent in mechanize, to try to get the web site to respond as if you're using Firefox?

Comment: @LarsH Ok, I understood. Mechanize is not able to process javascript which generates the link. I need to look at alternatives to that.

Answer (score 1):

Try setting your user agent before executing any requests

```
br = mechanize.Browser()
#Change the 2nd tuple entry to your particular user agent, you can check it in http://whatsmyuseragent.com/
br.addheaders = [('User-agent', 'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/42.0.2311.135 Safari/537.36')]
```